# Installing Vista via Bootable USB created on an XP computer

Tags: windows-vista, boot, format

I am trying to install Windows Vista on my laptop in which the CD drive no longer works. I decided I would install via USB flash drive. On that same laptop I created my bootable flash drive, vLited it to remove some undeeded things and now my laptop wont boot. It tells me that im missing a "hal.dll" file.

So now my laptop is out of commission fully. I have resorted to my old desktop which is running on windows xp. I want to create another bootable flash drive from an original unaltered copy of vista that i have just aquired. When I run DISKPART I cannot get the thing to show up in "LIST DISK" it just shows my computers harddrive. It is fully plugged in and shows up when I go to "my computer" as I: but not in diskpart. Any ideas why?

Im quite desperate now. And am willing to try anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: IT WORKED! I emulated vista on my desktop in order to format my drive and copy the files over for the install and then it installed perfectly! THANKS SUPERUSERS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are out of luck to create a bootable USB drive from XP which will work for installing Vista, according to [this blog article by James O'Neill at MS](http://blogs.technet.com/jamesone/archive/2006/12/31/bootable-usb-keys.aspx). You need to find a Vista / Win7 / Server 2008 machine to do this, or try and fix the install you already have as advised by harrymc.
And maybe don't vLite it next time round?

Comment: You think i can emulate vista on my xpdesk top to pull that off? Im not really savvy on the specifics of how emulation works.

Answer (score 1):

The following two articles relate to XP, but will probably also apply to Vista:

[Missing Or Corrupt Hal.dll Error Resolution](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/missinghaldll.htm)
[Restore Hal.dll From the Windows XP CD](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/restorehaldll.htm)